# Could not find "application" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Emberjs RailsAPI

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I've been stuck trying to find an answer or a fix to what seems a very simple issue.

I have recently started RailsAPI app. I decided to play around with EmberJS and follow a recent tutorial found [here](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ember/2013/01/07/building-an-ember-app-with-rails-api-part-1.html)

When I go to the index page of my app, all I see is a blank screen and my templates won't render. It seems that Ember is not able to find my templates for some reason.

Here's what I see in the console:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1 ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
generated -> route:application Object {fullName: "route:application"} ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
generated -> route:index Object {fullName: "route:index"} ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
generated -> controller:application Object {fullName: "controller:application"} ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
Could not find "application" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:application"} ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
generated -> controller:index Object {fullName: "controller:index"} ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
Could not find "index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:index"} ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
Transitioned into 'index' ember-1.0.0.js?body=1:394
=> Ember.TEMPLATES
   # Object {}
```

As you can see, the Ember.TEMPLATES is empty. My current app structure looks like this

```
Dojo
  - app
    - assets
      - javascripts
        - templates
          - application.hbs
          - index.hbs
        - application.js.coffee
        - router.js.coffee
    - controllers
```

And so on, I will update as needed. Its pretty much a basic Rails app.

Here's how my relevant files look like:

**application.js.coffee**

```
#= require jquery-1.9.1
#= require handlebars-1.0.0
#= require ember-1.0.0
#= require ember-data
#= require_self
#= require router
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./routes

window.AppDojoApi = Ember.Application.create
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
  LOG_BINDINGS: true
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true

console.log Ember.TEMPLATES
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='span12'>
        <div class='page-header'></div>
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**templates/index.hbs**

```
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

All of the necessary files (ember, handlebars, jQuery) are being rendered correctly because I don't see any errors in the console and they are in the HTML generated.

I'm using the gem `handlebar_assets` to compile the assets for the `AssetsPipeline` and the templates are being generated correctly.

Why wouldn't ember be able to find the templates? Thanks for the help

**UPDATE** Here's the source code if anyone is interested in taking a look at it https://github.com/AppDojo/AppDojo-API/tree/ember-railsapi

**SOLUTION**

Setting `HandlebarsAssets::Config.ember = true` set the right template storage for the templates to `Ember.TEMPLATES`. I was missing an `s` from Handlebars...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem lies in the fact that the handlebars template files extension should be `.hbs` instead of `.hb`, try to rename your templates to:

```
index.hbs
application.hbs
foo.hbs
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did see that after I posted the question. However, this does not fix my issue. Ember is not finding my templates. Apparently handlebar_assets gem puts them in an object called HandlebarTemplates. Is there any way to tell Ember to get them from there?

Comment: @LeoCorrea, do you have your `config/initializer/handlebars_assets.rb` properly setup? Also after making changes you should do manually `rm -rf tmp/*` to force every template to be regenerated

Comment: I do have the initializer set to ember and did the `rm -rf tmp/*` but no luck

Comment: So, I was missing an `s` in the `HandlebarsAssets::Config` options for the ember = true. That seemed to fix the it. Thanks!

Comment: @LeoCorrea, oh, glad I could help a bit :) thanks for accepting the answer anyway.